# Where can I put test data that is not part of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I want to test against a list of invalid email addresses. At the moment, they live in my `setup` method:

```rb
  def setup
    @invalid_email_addresses = [
      'plainaddress',
      '#@%^%#$@#$@#.com',
      '@domain.com',
      'Joe Smith <email@domain.com>',
      'email.domain.com',
      'email@domain@domain.com',
      '.email@domain.com',
      'email.@domain.com',
      'email..email@domain.com',
      'あいうえお@domain.com',
      'email@domain.com (Joe Smith)',
      'email@domain',
      'email@-domain.com',
      'email@domain.web',
      'email@111.222.333.44444',
      'email@domain..com'
    ]
  end
```

This makes the method rather long. I would like to move them to a `yml` file:

```
# test/fixtures/email_addresses.yml
invalid_email_addresses:
    - 'plainaddress'
    - '#@%^%#$@#$@#.com'
    - '@domain.com'
    - 'Joe Smith <email@domain.com>'
    - 'email.domain.com'
    - 'email@domain@domain.com'
    - '.email@domain.com'
    - 'email.@domain.com'
    - 'email..email@domain.com'
    - 'あいうえお@domain.com'
    - 'email@domain.com (Joe Smith)'
    - 'email@domain'
    - 'email@-domain.com'
    - 'email@domain.web'
    - 'email@111.222.333.44444'
    - 'email@domain..com'
```

But that results in an error for each test:

> ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: fixture key is not a hash: /Users/stefan_edberg/Rails/tennis_app/test/fixtures/emaild_addresses.yml, keys: ["invalid_email_addresses"]

If not in fixtures, where should I put these email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shared itself conveys that there is some problem in parsing the YAML contents. I saved the following contents in a file `test.yml` on my Desktop

```
# test/fixtures/email_addresses.yml
invalid_email_addresses:
  - 'plainaddress'
  - '#@%^%#$@#$@#.com'
  - '@domain.com'
  - 'Joe Smith <email@domain.com>'
  - 'email.domain.com'
  - 'email@domain@domain.com'
  - '.email@domain.com'
  - 'email.@domain.com'
  - 'email..email@domain.com'
  - 'あいうえお@domain.com'
  - 'email@domain.com (Joe Smith)'
  - 'email@domain'
  - 'email@-domain.com'
  - 'email@domain.web'
  - 'email@111.222.333.44444'
  - 'email@domain..com'
```

and then tried loading it from `irb` and it successfully loaded:

[image]

**Please Note**: Initially when I copied the YAML contents as it is in my file and tried loading it, I encountered parsing error and then I removed the following entry and tried again and the parse was successful

```
- 'あいうえお@domain.com'`
```

That entry contains Unicode characters. As YAML is indentation-sensitive copying that entry as it is in my file made the indentation inconsistent which caused parse error. Fixing the indentation for that entry made the parse successful.